Unit tests with Spark 3.4.1 and Java 17 fail even when using VM arguments
I am using using Java 17 (corretto-17) with Gradle (7.3.3) and Scala (2.12.17), when running intelliJ unit tests that uses Spark (3.4.1) it fails with an ExceptionInInitializerError/IllegalAccessError.
The most common answer I've seen is to add some VM arguments, like this thread suggests: Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: class StorageUtils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.
I tried to add the VM arguments in various places. The first thing I tried was Run -> Edit Configurations -> Modify Options -> Java -> Add VM options and pasted the list of options there.
IntelliJ run configurations screenshot
I also tried to add it to my gradle.build file like Chris suggested:
test {
    // Pass configuration to unit tests similarly to the way this would be run in an officially deployed environment.
    // (gradlew -Dprop=value may not otherwise work if test execution is forked)
    systemProperty 'log4j.configuration', "file:${project.rootDir}/config/log4j.properties"
    systemProperty 'APP_DIR', getProjectOrSystemProperty('APP_DIR', "${project.rootDir}")
    jvmArgs '-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
}

These are my testing jars:
// testing jars
junit: '4.13.1',
scalatest: '3.2.10',
scalatestplus: '3.2.10.0',
typesafeConfig: '1.2.1',
xmlUnit: '1.6',
sparkFastTests: '1.3.0',
mockito: '5.8.0',
mockitoScala: '1.16.0',
cucumber: '6.9.0',
infoCukes: '1.2.6',

Full stacktrace:

org.oclc.dataservices.bib.billingstats.BillingStatsTest >
initializationError FAILED
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x5e25a92e)
cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base)
because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module
@0x5e25a92e
at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.(StorageUtils.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.(StorageUtils.scala)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:464)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2740)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1026)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1020)
at org.x.x.utils.SparkSessionTestWrapper.setup(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:23)
at org.x.x.utils.SparkSessionTestWrapper.setup$(SparkSessionTestWrapper.scala:18)
at org.x.x.x.x.BillingStatsTest.setup(BillingStatsTest.scala:11)
at org.x.x.x.x.BillingStatsTest.(BillingStatsTest.scala:13)

Test class:
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class BillingStatsTest extends AnyFunSuite with BillingStats with SparkSessionTestWrapper with Logging {
  setLogLevel(Level.ERROR)
  val spark: SparkSession = setup()

The stacktrace from that IllegalAccess error points to the config line of wrapper class:
trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  def setup(): SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[2]")
      .appName("Spark local test")
      .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}

I just found this related thread: How to solve "Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries" when running spark code?. My local machine is connected to the company VPN, which might be relevant to this issue.

those params definitely work, perhaps it's down to how you are running your tests.  Can you provide some context on how you are running them please?

Hi Chris, I added details to my question. Thanks for replying, please take another look when you can.

now I'm even more confused - what is running your tests - is it maven / an ide / sbt / gradle?  Where does the VPN come into it?  Clearly the vm parameters you think are being passed in aren't, so something in your tool usage is amiss.

My local machine is connected to the company VPN. We are testing using intellij/gradle. The VM parameters are definitely being passed in, we can see it in the terminal when we build the project and our tests run.
"Executing 'build --info --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED'..."

ah ok, I'll provide an answer as formatting in comments isn't great

@ChewyLime4 can you update the question with a screenshot of your IDE run configuration for the application? that would make things clear as to verify if they are being really passed correctly or not. The access had not much to do with your network(VPN), so that's mostly irrelevant to the question.

Hi @Naman, I updated my question and included the screenshot.

Gradle, by default, runs tests in a single forked jvm, each fork uses new jvm arguments, as such in your config you need to ensure the test runs specify the correct args:
test {
    jvmArgs '--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED'
}


I'm still getting the error even after adding this to my build.gradle.
